# how to reuse the defined drawable with different colors in xml

Tags: android, android-drawable

Having drawable defined with one color:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="oval">
<corners android:radius="10dip"/>
<solid android:color="#FF7C71BF"/>
```

and used in layout for some item as:

```
android:background="@drawable/oval_shape"
```

if I would like to reuse this drawable in the layout xml at multiple places but with different colors, how to do it? (It could be done in code to reassign the color, just want to see if it is possible to be done using xml).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that only works with Lollipop and later:

Make the color white:

```
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
```

then use `backgroundTint` and `backgroundTintMode` attributes on the view:

```
        <View
            android:backgroundTint="#FF00FF00"
            android:backgroundTintMode="multiply"
            ....
```

In this example, it would be green.

For KitKat and earlier, those attributes don't exist so you would have to resort to code:

```
        setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

[Here's a tutorial for this method.](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/tinting-your-next-android-ui/)

Answer (score 0):

You cant do it in XML believe me.

In java code simply write as below:

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.view_id);
LayerDrawable bg = (LayerDrawable)v.getBackground();
final GradientDrawable shape = (GradientDrawable)   bg.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.drawable_id);
shape.setColor([any color]);
```

Comment: thanks Amir! we know it can be don in code, just want to know if there is way to do it in xml.